# I tried using other alerts like alertifyJS and sweetalert but they are not behaving like normal javascript alert.

Tags: javascript

I tried using other alerts like alertifyJS and sweetalert but they are not behaving like normal javascript alert.

Since, in javascript alert the execution of page stops at the time alert appears, but in these alert boxes i am seeing execution is going on even i have not closed the alert box. Kindly help me out to solve this or give me some alternatives.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but why don't you just use a normal alert? Without seeing your code and exactly what it is you want to stop executing it's difficult to know what to advise. It sounds like you merely want to call preventDefault() on whatever event is firing (e.g a form submit) but without code I think this question is likely to be closed.

Comment: See first of all i don't want to use alert because for my application i need some attractive alert boxes.

Comment: Now, i will provide you the chunk of code. 
if( resp.data.match("success")){
                                alert("Your response is successfully updated");
                                $location.path('/');
                        }
Here in this chunk if i will use alert like swal or alertifyjs , then the redirection will happen with prompt still opened.That is the exact problem i am facing.

Answer (score 3):

> Since, in javascript alert the execution of page stops at the time alert appears, but in these alert boxes i am seeing execution is going on even i have not closed the alert box.

This is normal for any kind of message display library that modifies the DOM to show the message.

If it blocked, then the click events would never be recognised and the browser would lock up.

They should provide some kind of callback mechanism to run a function when the OK button is clicked. Put the continuing logic in that function instead of immediately after the call to the message display library.

Answer (score 0):

They aren't behaving like the normal JavaScript `alert()` because they *can't* behave like a normal JavaScript `alert()`. There's no mechanism in JavaScript to just pause page execution.

Just put the code that needs to execute after the alert in the callback and you'll be fine.

Comment: How to put in the callback can you explain, since i am new to it.

Comment: if( resp.data.match("success")){
                                swag("Your response is successfully updated");
                                $location.path('/');
                        }

Comment: Suppose i have this chunk of code, now i want the redirection to happen only when popup is closed, how it happens in javascript alert, how can we do this.

Comment: Well, for instance, for SweetAlert, look at the examples using `then` at https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/ ...

Comment: Still, you are not getting my question,i am not worried about sweetalert usages. My scenerio is in the code provided above. If i use normal alert it will wait until i click ok then do redirection, but if i will use sweetalert even though prompt is there my page will trigger redirection.

Comment: You need to put the code that triggers redirection in the callback, not the next statement after the `alert()`.